# Why my Navbar is by default coming out to be inside "./components/Index"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

[image: Navbar]This 'Navbar' is a component which I have created inside 'components' and used a separate index file.js for exporting it to App.js but when I am importing this , it's coming out to be inside 'components/Index'

[image: LocalHost]

[image: Expecting this]
But the local host is coming out to be blank.
If I remove this Navbar Import, then also it's coming out to be blank with the containers. What mistakes could I be doing?

Answer (score 0):

You have to import the Navbar component like this

```js
import Navbar from './components/Navbar/Navbar'
```

and if you have index.js not a Navbar.jsx and Navbar.jsx code inside the index.js in Navbar dir then you have to import file like this

```js
import Navbar from './components/Navbar'
```

and if you have index.js in Navbar dir and also have Navbar.jsx and you import Navbar into that index file then you can use like the below code

```js
import Navbar from './Navbar'

export {Navbar}
```

and App.js import is like
import {Navbar} from './components/Navbar'

but currently you are wrapping your Navbar component into `{}` that not work because you I think set Navbar as default export Navbar like it you export navbar like export = {Navbar} something then you can import like that way but for current situation you can use first option that correct for you.